# Dose react native firebase admob support Native type?

Tags: react-native, admob, react-native-firebase

I follow this tutorial finish `Admob Banner`

https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-firebase-admob/

Admob has four types : `Banner` `Interstitial` `Rewarded` `Native`

But I can't find Native type in `react-native-firebase`.

Where can I find it ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-firebase for admob is an open issue on github. You can find more info here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1259.

You can use google admob, I used it in one of my application, it works fine. You can see following link:

https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-admob/

Comment: I used `react-native-admob` before. The library has been depreciated.